# Switch user and store command output in variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get command output into a variable when switching user in my script:

```
checkOutput="$(echo command1 | su - user1)"
```

But using `echo` on the variable does not return the desired result:

```
echo $checkOutput
```

Output:

```
Oracle Corporation SunOS ... January 2005 logout
```

Desired output (to be stored in variable):

```
Java version ...
Apache Qpid is RUNNING with PID=5227
```

When running command `echo command1 | su - user1` in terminal the output is:

```
Oracle Corporation SunOS ... January 2005
Java version ...

Apache QPID is RUNNING with PID=5227

logout
```

I know that when `su - user1` is called the script exits its current scope. Is there a way to store the output of the command? Or is this impossible using bash.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the actual command you tried and the actual output. The construction is correct and should work.

Comment: @AlexP I have edited my question to show more detailed output.

Comment: Maybe something is printed to the standard error. Try `"$(echo command | su - user1 2>&1)"`.

Comment: Try echo "$checkOutput"

Comment: @AlexP The output was being printed to stderr. The formatting of the string  is odd but it works. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you need to quote the parameter expression to preserve the newlines in your output: `echo "$checkOutput"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `script` command to log output in a file. So it would look something like this:

```
script -c '$(echo command1 | su - user1)' -f file.txt
```

You can then reference this file to get desired output from it.